Flutter | Hide/don't show keyboard when having focus on specific TextField, but allow input from external keyboard/scanner/nfc reader
I'm currently working on an app that gets it's input from an external nfc reader and saves it to a file. As the title says, I need a way to always hide the on-screen keyboard, but the TextField needs to allow input, so keyboardType: TextInputType.none or readOnly: true won't work, I've already tried that.
Since I am new to Flutter, I am not quite sure how to do this correctly and would appreciate any help I can get.
Versions:

Flutter 3.19.5
Dart 3.3.3

My build widget:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 0.5,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Image.asset("assets/logo/logo.png"),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 50),
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 80.0, height: 2.0, color: Colors.white60),
                  autofocus: true,
                  controller: _controller,
                  focusNode: _focusnode,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  enableSuggestions: false,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onSubmitted: (newValue) {
                    // does something
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                    alignLabelWithHint: true,
                    hintText: 'z.B.: 1092831023',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 80.0, height: 2.0, color: Colors.white60),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }

As already stated, this are the things I've already tried:
keyboardType: TextInputType.none and/or readOnly: true. I also tried this library, but it's quite outdated and doesn't work properly, as it shortly opens the keyboard briefly on every input character.

Try using the AbsorbPointer Widget on top of your TextField, like this:
                 AbsorbPointer(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: textController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )


Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem, as it still opens/shows the keyboard after external input. Also, I am unable to regain focus after unfocusing the TextField.
Thanks for your help though.
